# zip some modules including target directory from multi-module maven project

Tags: java, spring, maven, maven-plugin, maven-assembly-plugin

I have a multi-module maven project with the below hierarchy and wanted to create a zip after the mvn build and curl or upload it to one private repository. I am using the maven-assembly-plugin but it is not including the required directory. Please can you suggest something?

````
|--subproject1
   |--src/main/..
   |--resoruces/..
   |target/..
   |pom.xml
|--subproject2
   |--src/main/..
   |--resoruces/..
   |pom.xml
pom.xml```

content of zip.xml

    <assembly
        xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.2.xsd">
        <id>project</id>
        <formats>
            <format>zip</format>
        </formats>
        <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
        <!--<fileSet></fileSet>-->
          <fileSets>
            <fileSet>
                <directory>${project.basedir}/subproject1</directory>
                <outputDirectory></outputDirectory>
                <useDefaultExcludes>true</useDefaultExcludes>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*.log</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </fileSet>
          </fileSets>
            <files>
                <file>
                    <source> ${project.basedir}/pom.xml</source>
                    <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
                </file>
            </files>
    
    </assembly>
    
    below plugin is added in pom.xml of subproject1
    <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <phase>package</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>single</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <appendAssemblyId>true</appendAssemblyId>
                                <descriptors>
                                    <descriptor>zip.xml</descriptor>
                                </descriptors>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
````

I wanted to create a zip with subproject1 includes src, resources, and target folder. Kindly assist.

Comment: Using the jar command I am able to prepare a zip with the artifacts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using "jar -cf project.zip project-name" command, zip is getting created.